# The class of $0-1$ matrices with row sums at least $2$, where distinct columns have dot product $1$

Tags: matrices, terminology, binary

There is an $m\times n$ matrix of ones and zeros where the dot product of any two different columns is one and any row have at least two ones in it.

My question is: Is this a popular matrix? Does it have a name?

Comment: I think you might want to look at "Incidence Matrix".

Comment: @Element118 Try to put your comment as an answer so that others will recognize it directly + you will get a correct check sign ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is an incidence matrix. An incidence matrix is a matrix of ones and zeros in it, usually representing a relation of some sort.

However, stating that it is just an incidence matrix would neglect the properties that the dot product of any two different columns is 1 and that every row has at least 2 ones in it, hence these conditions should be explicitly stated.